# Excel find and replace everything except email addresses?

Tags: excel, email

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I have a folder with a large number of "undeliverable" emails. I managed to export the body of each email to an excel sheet. The actual email address is contained in each body but is accompanied by other text which I don't want. Is there a formula that will find all "@" and all the characters attached to it then replace everything else with blank?

```
Body
"Your message to email@address.com couldn't be delivered.

         email wasn't found at address.com"
```

A formula that would replace everything except "email@address.com"

Thanks for any ideas or help :)

Comment: Maybe you need to a macro for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)))-99,198))
```